# Techniques for finding a complete set of relations for a finitely presented group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

I am working on a problem where I want to find a presentation of a particular finite group. I have a particular transitive free action I'm interested in, and using this, I've been able to essentially work out the multiplication table for the group. But I would like to come up with a presentation in terms of generators and relations.

After playing around with it, I have found four relations that I believe to be all the relations I need. But I am at a loss for how to prove that these relations are all I need.

I know that formally a presentation is a free group in this case, $\mathcal{F}(x, y)$ quotiented by the normal closure of one of its subgroups. But I don't see this as giving me much leverage on the problem.

The best idea I have right now is to somehow (tediously) work out a procedure for normalizing words into a canonical form.

I am aware that this kind of problem skirts on the word problem and is likely undecidable in general. But what I am looking for is general strategies for attacking these kinds problems.

Comment: The general strategy is similar to your normal form idea, and may well be tedious: find a procedure for freely rewriting every word $w$ that represents the trivial element as some concatenation $p = v_1 r_1 v_1^{-1} ... v_K r_K v_K^{-1}$ of conjugates of relators, where by "freely rewriting" I mean that the only alterations allowed in getting between the given $w$ and the desired word $p$ are cancellation of generators. If you are working with a particular finite group with a multiplication table, you are not going to run into undecidability issues. But your job may be tedious nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks. I was just worried that I would go through a lot of work just to find out that some more clever algebraic trick would give the answer easily.